# Testing Twilio with ngrok tunnel to localhost results in bad host name error

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

In the past I've used ngrok to test twilio webhooks on my local machine - it's always worked.  I'm working on a new app that uses Co-Pilot (not sure if it has anything to do with co-pilot) and I'm getting the `11210` error: `HTTP bad host name`.

I initialize my tunnel with `/Applications/ngrok http -host-header=rewrite local.whicheversiteimworkingon.com:80`

The URL listed in the Message Text is `http://fcd0ed57.ngrok.io/sms/twilio/incoming` but the body shows

```
Twilio was unable to fetch content from: https://local.thesiteimworkingon.com/sms/twilio/incoming
Error: Unknown host local.thesiteimworkingon.com
Account SID: AC5a22f090b458f6942da879d347451dfd
SID: SM9c45741b5b70967df6a7e196e3bee552
Request ID: 9fde222c-14e1-448e-ad79-4a392d212ffd
Remote Host: local.thesiteimworkingon.com
Request Method: POST
Request URI: https://local.thesiteimworkingon.com/sms/twilio/incoming
SSL Version: TLSv1.2
URL Fragment: true
```

Unfortunately I don't have an example of this from when it was working - it's been months (maybe 12+) since I've had to do this.

[Update] I've confirmed this happens with co-pilot and regular numbers, starting to think it's environment related.

Have I misconfigured something in order to test this locally?

Comment: Is your application supporting the correct HTTP method? By default, Twilio uses a POST, maybe your application only responds with a GET?

Comment: Are you able to hit the ngrok URL in a browser and it work successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the `https` ngrok instead of `http`?

Comment: Same error: 
url = https://3681b876.ngrok.io/sms/twilio/incoming
`Twilio was unable to fetch content from: https://local.domain.com/sms/twilio/incoming?...`

Comment: Maybe test the ngrok and twilio webhook separately (using https://requestbin.com/ for twilio for example), to see exactly what to investigate

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It may be to do with the application server you are using expecting a different host name. When you start Ngrok, you can [pass the `--host-header` flag](https://ngrok.com/docs#http-host-header) to rewrite the host header for your application.

```
ngrok http 3000 --host-header=rewrite local.domain.com
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks @philnash - I'll update my question with more complete information, I do use the rewrite option